# Windows 7 slows down when I connect the laptop charger

Tags: windows-7, performance, charger

I have HP ProBook 4520s laptop running Windows 7. When I connect the laptop charger to electricity, Windows becomes very slow. However, when I disconnect the power, 
Windows returns to operating normally.

In this case it only happens when connected to my house's electricity; it does not happen elsewhere.

I searched for this problem but I couldn't find any solutions. Maybe the electricity affected the CPU, or maybe Windows settings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A user on an [hp forum](http://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Notebook-Lockups-Freezes-Hangs/HP-Probook-4520s-slow-down-while-charging-of-laptop-battery/td-p/1608279/page/2) suggests installing "HP Power Assistant". You may be able to find the application [here](http://www8.hp.com/us/en/drivers.html) by entering your product name or number in the readily available text field.

Comment: Oops, Chrome automatically translated that forum to english. Just a heads up.

Answer (score 1):

Check your 'Power Settings' when power is plugged in. Start-> Control Panel-> Power Options.

You may have to change to control panel view to 'Small Icons'.

Answer (score 0):

1. Check that you have the correct power adapter. Not just one that fits and charges the laptop. The correct manufacturer spec power brick. Using the incorrect power brick on our 6550b ProBooks led to months of back and forth with HP about a very similar issue to you.
2. Check the power settings aren't limiting CPU